# Adding ' to the start and end of each array value

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to add a ' to the end and the start of each array value. The reason for this is that I have a graph JQuery set up and want to manipulate the chart value names. I can do perfectly if I wanted them to be numbers however whenever I try using text I get an error, which I believe is because there aren't any ' at the start and end of my array values. Any ideas guys?

The error i'm getting is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: MyTextValue is not defined

```
var barNames = [];

if (NoOfBars >= 1){
    barNames = [name1];
}
if (NoOfBars >= 2){
    barNames = [name1, name2];
}
if (NoOfBars >= 3){
    barNames = [name1, name2, name3];
}
if (NoOfBars >= 4){
    barNames = [name1, name2, name3, name4];
}
if (NoOfBars >= 5){
    barNames = [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5];
}
if (NoOfBars >= 6){
    barNames = [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6];
}
if (NoOfBars >= 7){
    barNames = [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7];
}
if (NoOfBars >= 8){
    barNames = [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8];
}
if (NoOfBars >= 9){
    barNames = [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8, name9];
}
if (NoOfBars >= 10){
    barNames = [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8, name9, name10];
}

var bar = new RGraph.Bar({
    id:'cvs1',
    data: barValue,
    options: {
      backgroundGridDashed: true,
      labels: barNames,
      title: 'Title of Chart',
      strokestyle: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
      textAccessible: true
    }
}).draw();
```

Comment: Which error do you get? Is all your question just about e.g `name1` not being a variable but a string?

Comment: those are all interpreted as variables since they aren't quoted strings

Comment: Just added the error I'm getting.

Comment: nothing in code shown has `MyTextValue` in it..... code shown is not representative of the error thrown

Comment: MyTextValue was an example input not a variable

Comment: @MattHutch So you have to quote your names, these aren't varaibles but just strings...

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you this has resolved my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
barNames = [
    "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5",
    "name6", "name7", "name8", "name9", "name10"
].slice(0,NoOfBars);
```

It really depends on how these values are used.

Comment: Just added the method that i'm using this with. Also I gave this a go fortunately still no luck. Thanks for helping by the way.

Comment: @MattHutch This answer would fix your issue so you are testing it wrongly